# Как правильно использовать Observable

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, rxjs

Делаю так

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";

 let arr = [1, 2, 3];
 let test = Observable.from(arr);

test.subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

выводит 1, 2, 3

```
 arr.push(4);
 arr.push(5);
```

И ничего не выводит

Comment: не, это не так работает

Comment: наверно это не совсем то. https://pastebin.com/fyGXwgAr

Comment: используй Subject

Comment: да то что нужно, мне как раз нужно было вешать ивенты на объект и тригерить при изменении объекта